# Reinstall `env` program

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

So I've accidently overwritten my `/usr/bin/env` program. Is there a way I can restore it?

when i type

```
env
```

in the shell it says "the program env is not installed you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install coreutils
```

But when I try that, it says i already have the latest version installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```